# Log user name and password to text file from form

Tags: forms, post, asp-classic

We have a very old client that is having problems trying to log in to a website. At the moment we think the user is not entering a correct username.

The site is in ASP does any one have any code that I could borrow that would be able to log and write down whats posted and then post that user name and password to the normal submit function.

Comment: Saving client passwords in plain-text anywhere is almost always a very, very bad idea. Surely there are more straightforward means of determining if this old client is mistyping his username?

Comment: I was thinking of writing the file outside of the root folder for security reasons. From the log files of IIS all I can see is that he is hitting a page that is showing page user/name password.


I have tried logging in with his username and password both are not case sensertive. I have tried logging in with IE and FF and even wget and all works.

The user is very old and i am sure its a user error but I just can not spot it.

If the site was php based i would not have a issue but its ASP so a little bit stuck

Comment: Maybe the user is doing it right? Maybe the software is at fault? Just a thought....

Comment: Can you create a user on the system and log in without error?
Can the user recover username/password information?
If both these satisfied, how much trouble is a user worth? (business decision) Can you reset the username password and send to user?

Answer (score 1):

Send the old client an email asking him what his username is. He'll probably mistype it in his reply the same way he mistypes it in the web form.

Comment: password is "welcome" I am not sure if you can muck that up I have called him on the phone and said you are typing in "W E L C O M E" yes and your username "D A V I D" The guy is in his 70's I am just lost as to what the problem could be.

Comment: What about writing the password as a MD5 string for you people who are worried about security "40be4e59b9a2a2b5dffb918c0e86b3d7" is welcome

Comment: Just added some javascript checking to make sure there is a user name and password entered still no joy.

Comment: Tried in crome still no issue user is using IE7

Answer (score 1):

Give him a call, and tell him to spell out each letter/keystroke as he tries to log in.